# MVC javascript - After reload Model object in javascript is not refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, json, asp.net-mvc, model

In MVC application, I have a javascript that accesses Model elements as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () { setColors(); });

function setColors() {

    var results = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.saVM.results));
     $(results).each(function (indexRes, itemRes){
           alert(itemRes.ResultTypeID);
    });
}
</script>
```

one property in Model.saVM.results (ResultTypeID) is initially null, but when i reload my table, this property has a value. However in my setColor function this property is still null.

**_SearchPanel**

```
function refreshGrid() { 
      $('#mapsDiv').load(url, { ... },
           function (data) {});


      setColors();}
```

The first script is present in About.cshtml, whereas refreshGrid function is present in another partial view (_SearchPanel)

**About.cshtml**

```
@model SuperMapModel
 <div>
 @Html.Partial("_SearchPanel", Model.scM)
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive" id="mapsDiv">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Maps/_MapDetailsList.cshtml", Model.saVM)
  </div>
 </div>
 <script> ... </script>
```

partial view _MapDetailsList contains html table that binds with Model.saVM...

On refresh/reload of grid i again call setColor function and again **ResultTypeID** property is null

```
function refreshGrid() { setColors();}
```

Comment: Can you put `setColors()` function in partial view?

Comment: yo that worked :)

Comment: are you adding an answer or i would?

Comment: Ok. Will post as answer then ;)

Comment: Out of curosity let me as what are you actually trying to achieve by looping results in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put setColors() function in partial view.
Should work.